# Control reaches end of a non-void function

Tags: c++

With regard to the following code:

```
public: int TreeWidth(struct node *root, int level)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (level == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (level > 1) {
        return TreeWidth(root->Left_link, level - 1) +
            TreeWidth(root->Right_link, level - 1);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain know why I am receiving the error mentioned in the title?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: Please enter your code in the question, not as a geaphical link. I'll fix it if I get to a non-phone device before someone else fixes it :-)

Comment: Looks like no one else beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 5):

If `level` is less than one and `root` is not `NULL` then no value will be returned. You need to return a value for *every* possible code path.

Probably the *easiest* way to fix it, assuming that you will never pass in a level of less than one (i.e., that's the topmost level of the tree), is to make a slight modification:

```
public:

int TreeWidth(struct node *root, int level) {
    if ((root == NULL) || (level < 1) return 0;
    if (level == 1) return 1;
    return TreeWidth(root->Left_link, level - 1) + TreeWidth(root->Right_link, level - 1);
}
```